# refresh materialized view periodically postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

for optimization purposes I'm using a materialized view, to refresh it periodically I have set a cron job that runs each period t in my case every three hours.
my questions are:

1. what's the best way to refresh a materialized view?
2. what can go wrong if using a cron job to refresh a materialized view?

I have come across a postgres plugin that schedule jobs [link](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron)

Comment: A cron job is a good way to do that, there is nothing wrong with it

Comment: thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name, I was just trying to be proactive as I can't account for all possible cases, and a failure of the view will be costly.

Comment: you can also consider https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the best way is to execute periodically a script that does the task:

the script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
psql -U user_name -d database_instance_name -c 'refresh materialized view view_name'
```

and add an entry in the crontab like:

```
@hourly  /full_path/script_name.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Also [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) extension can do job for Linux installation.
Here is a example that i use, refreshing every 5 minute;

```
INSERT INTO cron.job (schedule, command, nodename, nodeport, database, username)
VALUES ('*/5 * * * *', 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW public.mv_anyquery', 
'127.0.0.1', 5432, 'geodb', 'postgres');
```

nodename(127.0.0.1) may be necessary trust authentication in pg_hba.conf.