# How can I use materialized views in postgres when I want to append daily data to it?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I am new to Postgres. Can anybody suggest me a framework or method to use materialized views to append daily data into a historical data?

Here is the reason I am asking this question :

1. I have a historical materialized view which is dependent on unions of multiple matviews as it an expensive Query.
2. I need to append daily data to this historical mat view on a daily basis.

I am looking for an incremental refresh option in particular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [refresh materialized view periodically postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012961/refresh-materialized-view-periodically-postgres)

Comment: @JGH I'm looking for an incremental refresh option and not to refresh the whole materialize view as it is an expensive query.

Comment: There is no incremental refresh for MViews in Postgres. Maybe the extension [PipelineDB](https://www.pipelinedb.com/) could help you